# Taylors formula using little-o notation proof argument (continuity)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

Im trying to prove the following:

Let $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ be $C^n$ on $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $P_n$ be the $n$'th degree Taylor polynomial with $a$ as the expansion point then

$$
f(x) = P_n(x) + o\left((x-a)^n)\right)
$$

To those unfamiliar with this notation, I'm essentially trying to prove that

$$\dfrac{f(x) - P_n(x)}{(x-a)^n} \to 0 \ \text{as} \ x \to a$$

First off, I have utilized the Lagrange remainder form of Taylors formula to rewrite $f(x)$ and the definition of the Taylor polynomial to rewrite $P_n(x)$.

$$
\dfrac{f(x) - P_n(x)}{(x-a)^n} = \dfrac{P_{n-1}(x) + \dfrac{f^{(n)}(\xi_x)}{n!}(x-a)^n - P_{n-1}(x) - \dfrac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n}{(x-a)^n} 
$$

which simplifies to

$$
\dfrac{f^{(n)}(\xi_x) - f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}
$$

Here $\xi_x$ is a point between $x$ and $a$ so it is a different $\xi$ for every $x$. Now I utilize the continuity of $f$ in $a$. Given $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ so that

$$
|t-a|<\delta \implies |f^{(n)}(t)-f^{(n)}(a)|< \varepsilon
$$

If we pick $\delta$ so that

$$
|x-a| < \delta \implies \left| f^{(n)}(x) - f^{(n)}(a) \right| < n! \varepsilon
$$

we can be sure that $\xi_x$ is within $\delta$ of $a$ since it is between $x$ and $a$ and therefore we get

$$
\left|\dfrac{f(x) - P_n(x)}{(x-a)^n}\right| = \left| \dfrac{f^{(n)}(\xi_x) - f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} \right| < \dfrac{n! \varepsilon}{n!} = \varepsilon
$$

Now comes the question. Why is this sufficient to prove the limit? According to my textbook this is all it takes but I don't get how this prove that the limit is $0$ as $x$ goes to $a$

Comment: How does your textbook define the notion of limit of a function in a point? (in the fact one doesn't need the Lagrange remainder to show, $f(x)=P_n(x) + o((x-a)^n)$ if $f$ is n times continuously differentiable. It is just a trivial application of Rolle's theorem.)

Comment: In my textbook $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$ $f(x) \to b$ as $x \to a$ is defined as $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 \forall x \in A : |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - b| < \varepsilon$. I see now that is exactly what I have shown. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it was useful.